# ERC20: insufficient allowance error after using approve function while testing Vesting Vault fund function [Brownie]

Tags: solidity, erc-20, brownie, defi

I made a vesting vault with one beneficiary set on construction and a one time fund function which can be only called by the owner. The fund function funds the contract with ERC-20 tokens and sets an unlock time. The problem comes when testing the fund function with ERC20: insufficient allowance error even though I have used the approve function.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

error BeneficiaryZeroAddressError(address beneficiary);
error AlreadyFundedError(bool funded);
error TokenZeroAddressError(address token);
error InsufficientFundAmountError(uint256 amount);
error InsufficientLockedTimeError(uint256 lockedTime);
error WithdrawerNotBeneficiaryError(address beneficiary);
error VaultNotFundedError(bool funded);
error UnlockTimeNotPassedError();

contract VestingVault is Ownable{
    event ERC20Funded(address token, uint256 amount);
    event ERC20Withdrawn(address token, uint256 amount);

    address private immutable _beneficiary;
    address public tokenVestedAddress;
    uint256 public amountVested;
    uint256 public unlockTime;
    bool public funded = false;
    IERC20 public token;

    constructor(address beneficiary) {
        if(beneficiary == address(0)) revert BeneficiaryZeroAddressError(beneficiary);
        _beneficiary = beneficiary;
    }

    // public functions

    function fund(address tokenAddress, uint256 amount, uint256 lockedTime) public onlyOwner {
        if(funded) revert AlreadyFundedError(funded);
        if(tokenAddress == address(0)) revert TokenZeroAddressError(address(tokenAddress));
        if(amount <= 0) revert InsufficientFundAmountError(amount);
        if(lockedTime <= 0) revert InsufficientLockedTimeError(lockedTime);

        token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        emit ERC20Funded(tokenAddress, amount);

        funded = true;
        tokenVestedAddress = tokenAddress;
        amountVested = amount;
        unlockTime = block.timestamp + lockedTime;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        if(msg.sender != getBeneficiary()) revert WithdrawerNotBeneficiaryError(getBeneficiary());
        if(!funded) revert VaultNotFundedError(funded);
        if(block.timestamp < unlockTime) revert UnlockTimeNotPassedError();

        token = IERC20(tokenVestedAddress);
        token.transfer(getBeneficiary(), amountVested);
        emit ERC20Withdrawn(tokenVestedAddress, amountVested);
    }

    // view functions

    function getBeneficiary() public view returns (address) {
        return _beneficiary;
    }

    function getAmountVested() public view returns (uint256) {
        return amountVested;
    }

    function getUnlockTime() public view returns (uint256) {
        return unlockTime;
    }

    function getTimeUntilUnlocked() public view returns (uint256) {
        return unlockTime - block.timestamp;
    }
}
```

This is the test:

```
from brownie import VestingVault, TestERC20, accounts
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def vaultContract():
    vaultContract = VestingVault.deploy(accounts[1], {"from": accounts[0]})
    return vaultContract

@pytest.fixture
def tokenContract():
    tokenContract = TestERC20.deploy(100_000 * (10**18), {"from": accounts[2]})
    return tokenContract

# fund function
def test_fund(vaultContract, tokenContract):
    assert vaultContract.funded() == False
    tokenContract.transfer(accounts[0], 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})
    tokenContract.approve(accounts[0], 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})
    vaultContract.fund(tokenContract.address, 100, 10, {"from": accounts[0]})
```

- accounts[0] is the owner of the VestingVault contract
- accounts[1] is the beneficiary of the VestingVault contract
- accounts[2] is the owner of the TestERC20 contract

I have tried the transfer function in fund() in VestingVault.sol and I get the ERC20: transfer amount exceeds balance error even though I have transfered the tokens to the account. Also I tried to use `tokenContract.approve(vaultContract.address, 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})` but still get the same error.

I have also used the OpenZeppelin contract ERC20PresetFixedSupply.sol for testing but got the same errors. This is the current ERC20 contract that I am using for testing.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract TestERC20 is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20("TestERC20", "TERC20") {
        _mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
    }
}
```

This is the full error message:

```
    def test_fund(vaultContract, tokenContract):
        assert vaultContract.funded() == False
        tokenContract.transfer(accounts[0], 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})
        tokenContract.approve(accounts[0], 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})
>       vaultContract.fund(tokenContract.address, 100, 10, {"from": accounts[0]})
E       brownie.exceptions.VirtualMachineError: revert: ERC20: insufficient allowance
E       Trace step -1, program counter 827:
E         File "contracts/VestingVault.sol", line 43, in VestingVault.fund:    
E           if(lockedTime <= 0) revert InsufficientLockedTimeError(lockedTime);
E       
E           token = IERC20(tokenAddress);
E           **token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);**
E           emit ERC20Funded(tokenAddress, amount);
E        
E           funded = true;

tests/test_vestingVault.py:25: VirtualMachineError
```

Comment: As you are transferring the tokens from the msg.sender to the contract, at that particular interface call the `msg.sender` for `token` contract `approve` function will be the contract from which you are sending the interface call. So `VestingVault` contract should be allowed  to spend the tokens.
The approve function should go like `tokenContract.approve(VestingVaultaddress , 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})`

Comment: I have already tried that and it did not work. I get the same error. My bad I forgot to write that, I will do it now.

Comment: ACTUALLY YOU HAVE TO APPROVE THE CONTRACT FROM THE OWNER OF THE VESTING VAULT CONTRACT.
`tokenContract.approve(VestingVaultaddress , 10000, {"from": accounts[0]})`

Because you are sending tokens from the account[0] not account[2]

Comment: This passes the test, but I'm not 100% sure why. Could you explain a bit more please. I'm not exactly sure why do I need to use the VestingVault address in approve.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delayed response.
Actually when you call any function in a contract say contract `A` from another contract `B`  through interface,
at that particular call the msg.sender for the contract `A` is the address of contract `B`.
As you called the transferFrom method, the msg.sender is contract `B` means contract B's address is signing the transaction, so it needs to be approved.
The contract `A` doesn't know anything about which wallet you used to trigger the function in contract `B`. The msg.sender will always be contract B's address.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount).
But, transferFrom performs like so:

```
 function transferFrom(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint256 amount
    ) public virtual override returns (bool) {
        address spender = _msgSender();
        _spendAllowance(from, spender, amount);
        _transfer(from, to, amount);
        return true;
    }
```

You shouldn't call vaultContract.fund with accounts[0].

Try this instead

```
tokenContract.approve(VestingVaultaddress, 10000, {"from": accounts[2]})
vaultContract.fund(tokenContract.address, 100, 10, {"from": accounts[2]})
```

Let me know if that works

Comment: That can't work because ```vaultContract.fund(tokenContract.address, 100, 10, {"from": accounts[2]})``` must be called with accounts[0] which is the owner since ```fund()``` function can only be called by the owner

Comment: Then use tokenContract.approve(VestingVaultaddress, 10000, {"from": accounts[0]})
vaultContract.fund(tokenContract.address, 100, 10, {"from": accounts[0]})